# boost serialization and deserialization for different derived classes

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

Some classes have same variables and they all need serialization, so I wanna define an abstract class and it has two pure virtual fucntions `serialize()` and `deserialize()` so that these classes can inherit it and override the functions.

However, I found that the overridden functions are all duplicate code, like the following:

```cpp
void Derived::serialize() {
    ...
    ofstream ofs(file, ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << (*this);
}

void Derived::deserialize() {
    ...
    ifstream ifs(file, ios::binary);
    boost::archive::bianry_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> (*this);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the template desing pattern a viable way? https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method You can group the common code together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe that you serialize `*this` which is `Base&`. Because that's not a pointer type, there's no way you can deserialize derived types. This makes me question what kind of class hierarchy you really have.

I present to complete examples:

1. Non-Virtual Hierarchy
2. Virtual Hierarchy / Polymorphic Serialization

### 1. Non-Virtual Hierarchy

You could employ CRTP to do something that *does* depend on the derived type:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7353ab8669bbc80)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <fstream>

template <typename Derived> class Base {
  public:
    void serialize() const
    {
        //...
        std::ofstream ofs(file, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << as_derived();
    }

    void deserialize() {
        //...
        std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> as_derived();
    }

  protected:
    std::string file = "base.bin";

  private:
    int base_data = 42;
    Derived& as_derived()             { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); } ;
    Derived const& as_derived() const { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); } ;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
    {
        ar
            & base_data
            & as_derived().common_derived_data
            ;
    }
};

struct Derived1 : Base<Derived1> {
  private:
    friend class Base;
    std::array<float, 30> common_derived_data = {1,1,1,1};
};

struct Derived2 : Base<Derived2> {
  private:
    friend class Base;
    std::array<float, 30> common_derived_data = {2,2,2,2};
};

int main() {
    Derived1 x;
    Derived2 y;

    x.serialize();
    system("xxd base.bin");
    x.deserialize();

    y.serialize();
    system("xxd base.bin");
    x.deserialize();
}
```

Note:

This is no longer a virtual hierarchy. Polymorphic types [impose constraints on Boost Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers). You will want to stick to the Boost approach. Perhaps use a simple free function template to help out with repeated code?

### 2. Virtual Hierarchy / Polymorphic Serialization

Example:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13ca37a48090942b)**

Note:

- serialization MUST be through a pointer
- serialization MUST be through a pointer to Base (or at least the same type as serialized always, so *a* base class is the only thing that makes sense)
- types MUST be registered (or assumed abstract), see BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT et al.
- the `repeated_serialization_code` function template is now the home to repeated serialization code.
- note that that MUST include `base_object`
- `This` can be deduced const/non-const depending on call context.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <fstream>

class Base {
  public:
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

    virtual ~Base() = default;

    static void serialize(std::string file, Ptr const& ptr) 
    {
        //...
        std::ofstream ofs(file, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << ptr;
    }

    static Ptr deserialize(std::string file) {
        Ptr ptr;
        //...
        std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> ptr;

        return ptr;
    }

  protected:
    int base_data = 42;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& base_data; }

    template <typename Ar, typename This>
    static inline void repeated_serialization_code(Ar& ar, This& self, unsigned)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(self)
           & self.common_derived_data;
    }
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
  private:
    friend class Mixin;
    std::array<float, 30> common_derived_data = {1,1,1,1};

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend class Base;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned v) {
        repeated_serialization_code(ar, *this, v);
    }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
  private:
    friend class Mixin;
    std::array<float, 30> common_derived_data = {2,2,2,2};

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend class Base;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned v) {
        repeated_serialization_code(ar, *this, v);
    }
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived1)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived2)

int main() {
    Base::Ptr x = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
    Base::Ptr y = std::make_unique<Derived2>();

    Base::serialize("x.bin", x);
    system("xxd x.bin");
    auto x2 = Base::deserialize("x.bin");

    Base::serialize("y.bin", y);
    system("xxd y.bin");
    auto y2 = Base::deserialize("y.bin");
}
```

Comment: Added a second demo showing the virtual class hierarchy approach. See the notes for all the things that important to then pay attention to!

Comment: (a third option could be to move the common derived class members/code into a Mixin type, so you inherit `Base -> Mixin -> Derived*)